# Reading and using cell values from CSV file with Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV with column header in the first row, and ID on the first left column. I want to make a Python script that will take the text inside the table cell and put in a variable. I was think using loop to with increment of 1 to iterate with the id, the problem is the id is not in order i.e. 7,17,20,25,34 very random. *Note I can not change this as it is the identifier for another file. But I think I still need to use a loop as it is a large CSV file.

The column header I have is id, name, and text. I want a way to go through the text column of every rows on the file. Is there a way I can approach this?
PS. the variable I am putting the text in, will have other text appended it it later

I tried using the DictReader to import the CSV into Python. But I am not sure what to do next or if there is an alternative method

```
import csv
import os
import pprint

reader = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv','rb'))

dict_list = []
for l in reader:
    dict_list.append(l)

pprint.pprint(dict_list)
```

Comment: It would be best to include the first few lines of your csv file too, as well as an expected output so those wanting to answer can test their code before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to understand the problem without the .csv file sample or a better understanding of the output you would like, but DictReader should use the first row to label the columns automatically per the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader.

So, if all you want is the text column to be appended, you should be able to change your

```
dict_list.append(l)
```

line to

```
dict_list.append(l['text'])
```

and achieve the results you are looking for.